# Excel if statement for 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this question has been already asked a few times, but every statement that I try I end up with error messages.

I need a simple excel if statement where I can try out 3 possibilities:

[image: Dates]

I need to check 3 date columns, A1, B1 and C1. If all 3 are fullfilled, I need to subtract either C1 or B1 by A1. If B1 is empty, then I need to subtract C1 by A1. If C1 is empty, then I need to subtract B1 by A1. By all other results I need 0 to be returned.

Can anyone help me with that? I'm using excel 2016.

I tried the following statement:
=IF(B2<>"";B2;C2)-A2

But it doesn't really cover all cases.

Comment: I see your sample data, but where do you want your output? Can you give us a before/after example? Are you looking for a formula solution, or VBA?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54295318/edit) to add the statements you have tried and explain how they fail to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Also, if all 3 cells have a date, what do you want the output to be? "Either C1 or B1" isn't much help. Which one is it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have two dates, what I need is, respeting the conditions I mentioned, to subtract one date from another and have a final result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Math Version

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",C1<>""),AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",C1="")),B1-A1,IF(AND(A1<>"",B1="",C1<>""),C1-A1,0))
```

---

### Excel Version

```
=IF(OR(COUNT(A1:C1)=3,AND(ISBLANK(C1),COUNT(A1:B1)=2)),B1-A1,IF(AND(ISBLANK(B1),COUNT(A1:C1)=2),C1-A1,0))
```

Comment: While awaiting pnuts' version

Comment: hey @VBasic2008, thanks for your help! Do you mind explaining to me what's exactly is your formula doing? Why using count?

Also, I wanted to keep the date format on the end result. I'm getting only numbers with your formula. How can I adapt this to subtract the date properly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Renato: When you subtract one date from another, the difference is a number (of days).

Comment: Thanks very much @VBasic2008, your solution fixed my problem! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same result for sample as accepted 'Excel Version' A except for *all 3 are fullfilled* case:

```
=IF(A1="",0,MAX(A1:C1)-MAX(MIN(A1:C1),0))
```

Assumes Brazilian date formats.

Whatever the garbled English is supposed to mean (there is an SE site for a Portuguese version of SO) the results of the first two rows are not required to be the same:

The second row of the example is blank for (I assume, since OP has not bothered to clarify cell references) C1, hence:

> If C1 is empty, then I need to subtract B1 by A1

The first row is however populated in all three cells, hence:

> If all 3 are fullfilled, I need to subtract either C1 or B1 by A1

In the first row (and indeed all rows in the sample) B1 and A1 are not the same. So for that row there are two *different* results, which therefore cannot both be the same as any other (single) result, such as whatever is the result for the second row.

Comment: Almost. But the results of the first two rows have to be the same.