# Excel formula to subtract dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula where I can subtract dates from 3 columns based on a few conditions:

```
=IF(OR(COUNT(D15:F15)=3; AND(ISBLANK(F15); COUNT(D15:E15)=2)); E15-D15; IF(AND(ISBLANK(E15); COUNT(D15:F15)=2); F15-D15; 0))
```

The problem is, when the date from the column D is blank, I get a huge number on my result, because excel interprets blank as a random date.

I need to adapt this formula to make it return 0 whenever the D column has a 0 or blank value.

Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: `IF(OR(D15="",D15 = 0),0,<your formula here>)`?

Comment: Excel interprets blanks as zero because it is. A date minus 0 is going to be a 5 digit number that is equal to the original date (excel stores date as the number of days since it's date epoch (1970-01-01)).

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad tried your fix but it doesn't really seem to be working

Comment: @JNevill I'm going to be that guy...Excel's epoch is 1900.

Comment: Someone's gotta be that guy. My quick Google search must have flopped at brought me the Unix epoch. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, comparing a blank cell to `0` will return true, so the tests are easiler than you think.

Secondly, here's a simpler version of the formula

Thirdly, the answer this *this* Q: `If(D15=0,0, ...)`

Here's the improved formula, for row 15

```
=IF(D15=0,0,IF(E15=0,IF(F15=0,0,F15-D15),E15-D15))
```

Comment: Note that [your original Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295318/excel-if-statement-for-3-columns) was ambiguous as to what result you want if all three columns contain dates, and your reply to [Urdearboy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295318/excel-if-statement-for-3-columns#comment95411514_54295318) comment was not helpful